# Background doesn't show up in the View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have ready view with background but when i call it here, i don't see it. What should i do?

When i deleted Form{}, my background appeared.

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @State private var salaryPh: String = "" // should be int
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                BackgroundView()
                
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Your netto-salary per hour")) {
                        TextField("My salary is...", text: $salaryPh)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
                        

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opaque `Form` is on top of the `BackgroundView`, so hides it.

To make your `BackgroundView` visible, just add

```
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
```

to your `From`, e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var salaryPh: String = "" // should be int
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                BackgroundView()
                
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Your netto-salary per hour")) {
                        TextField("My salary is...", text: $salaryPh)
                    }
                }
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BackgroundView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
    }
}
```

[image]